NextJS v14 revalidatePath doesn't revalidate
I have a simple NextJS app with Prisma models. One page.tsx under the app/(authorized)/items folder and /items pathname:
  const Items = async () => { 
    const items: items[] = await getItems()
    return items.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>)
  }

and actions.ts:
  'use server'
                               
  import { db } from '@/lib/db'
                               
  export async function getItems() {
    const items = await db.item.findMany()
    return items              
  } 

and api route.ts:
  export async function POST(request: Request) {
    ...
             
    const response = await db.item.create({ data })
    revalidatePath('/(authorized)/items')
    return NextResponse.json(response, { status: 201 })

It should work, but it doesn't. It doesn't refresh data on /items page. Still keeps the old data.
Am I missing something? NextJs v14 bug?

I think the problem is your path. /(authorized)/items is a route group. So your page url actually will be something like this www.foo.com/items not www.foo.com/(authorized)/items.
Try
revalidatePath('/items');


Tried, doesn't work.

Oh sorry, I just checked the official docs and it says you can revalidate route groups too. Maybe Route Segment Config page can help you.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config

Adding the following at the bottom of the API route makes the pages/layout always render dynamically
export const revalidate = 0

if the above one doesn't work then add
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'


I followed the docs, doesn't work.

I think you have to do it differently, indeed it seems to pass but you revalidate the paths to have the new data before returning the answer, which is not necessarily a good practice, I advise you to revalidate the paths after the execution of your Endpoint or in case of success of this one;
Just make the move...

Please provide some code. What do you mean after execution? It should be done on the server side.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath#route-handler  it looks like they're wrong in the docs?
